# How to reverse the order of elements on a CSS flip animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I currently have a basic CSS animation that allows an image to be flipped and the reverse side shown, being a plain white background. This is displayed using a pseudo element.

**CSS:**

```
.flipOut {
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.flipOut:after {
    content:'';
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

I also require a class that can be toggled called `flipIn`. This will need to show the pseudo element first, being the white background, and then it will need to flip into the image. Hence, being the complete reverse of the current class.

How can I achieve this?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srvs3ra4/)**

---

**EDIT:**
Probably should have mentioned, but after the element is flipped and the white side is shown, I am removing the element completely and instantiating a new element. The new element needs to then flip in, giving the effect that the first element was flipped into the new element.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `transform rotateY value to 354deg`, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/srvs3ra4/3/)

```
transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(354deg);
```

Comment: Probably should have mentioned, but after the element is flipped and the white side is shown, I am removing the element completely and instantiating a new element. The new element needs to then flip in, giving the effect that the first element was flipped into the new element.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this wil help u.[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srvs3ra4/5/)

add FlipIn class with rotateY(-180deg);

```
    .flipIn{

      -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
      -ms-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
         -o-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
       -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
      transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);

       }
    .image{
        -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
        -o-transition: all 1s linear;
       -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
        transition: all 1s linear;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> transform: scaleX(-1); filter: FlipH;

```
.flipOut {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
            transform: scaleX(-1);
            filter: FlipH;
            -ms-filter: "FlipH";

            /*-moz-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
            -ms-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
            -o-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
            transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);*/

            -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
            -o-transition: all 1s linear;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
            transition: all 1s linear;
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

        }
```